# Cant get Spring @Value Property injection to work

Tags: spring, groovy, properties, dependency-injection

I have a configuration class annotated with `@SprintBootApplication`, and an `application.properties file` in the root of my classpath (`resources/application.properties`) with a value that reads

```
jmx.rmi.host="localhost"
```

i then have a separate component defined like this to try out `@Value` injection like this

```
@Component
class Props {

    private Map props = [:]
    boolean jmxEnabled
    String host

    @Autowired  //test inject the env
    Props (Environment env) {
        jmxEnabled = env.getRequiredProperty("org.softwood.jmx", Boolean.class)
        props[jmxEnabled]=jmxEnabled


    }

    void setHost (@Value ('${jmx.rmi.host}') String host)  {

        assert host
        println "set host by injection"
        this.host = host
        props[host] = host
    }

}
```

My first problem was solved as I was trying the `@Value` in "" - Gstring - fails.  So converted back to '' - String and its happy.

In my sample app script - i get the spring context and get a rulesEngine bean, then try and get my example Props bean.

The constructor injection using the autowired env seems to work. But the method injection using `@Value` to host gets nothing. Host is null when i try the assert, and not 'localhost' which i expected.

I'm missing something simple and i'm not seeing it, can any point out what I have done wrong

PS: I tried this on the core config class 
`@PropertySource ("classpath:application.properties")`

and tried defining this as bean as well

```
@Bean
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
}
```

as well but to no effect, i still get a null for method injection using `@Value`

any help would be gratefully received

Comment: Putting it on the setter will do nothing, just add it on the field or the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Put the annotation on the setter method rather than the parameter:

```
@Value('${jmx.rmi.host}') 
void setHost (String host)  {

    assert host
    println "set host by injection"
    this.host = host
    props[host] = host
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it still gets a null,  the method now looks like  @Value ('${jmx.rmi.host}')
    void setHost (String host)  {...    the injected env still works ok on the constructor

Comment: do you need another annotation somewhere to get the @Value injection from application.properties to work ?

Comment: actually it appears to be neither i've just the assert fails, assert p.host == "localhost"  but it shows the injected host value as "localhost".  So the injection worked but localhost does not equal localhost!  let me see whats wrong with that

Comment: my application.properties had quotes round localhost jmx.rmi.host="localhost", so the injected value included the "" as well.  If i remove the quotes from the prop file it gets the right answer

Comment: So my last question - why does @value work on the method - but not for the parameter?, could of sworn i'd seen an example of the parameter injection style in someone else sample ?

Comment: um t=yes there was - they used Autowired on the method, and Value on the param - tried that and that also injects correctly - peculiar

Comment: i had if you add `@Autowired` to method and `@Value` to the param it works also